# Get Manager Name based on User in SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am in need of your support.
I am into SharePoint Online environment and I am trying to get manager's name automatically pop up when a user is trying to fill the data in the modern view of List.

Could you please let me know steps how can we achieve it.
Waiting for your response.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use Person or Group column to auto-populate the manager, default values for People fields are not possible:
[SharePoint O365/Online Default value for Person or Group field with XML or CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236588/sharepoint-o365-online-default-value-for-person-or-group-field-with-xml-or-csom)

Consider using Flow to update the list column with manager’s user account, or use PowerApps forms instead.

Please see the references here:
[Set a people field in SharePoint with Power Automate when all you have is a user’s name.](https://sharepains.com/2018/11/05/microsoft-flow-set-a-people-field-in-sharepoint-when-all-you-have-is-a-users-name/) /
[Set Default Value To Person Or Group Field In PowerApps.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-default-value-to-person-or-group-field-in-powerapps/)